# Null Pointeer Exception in a Custom Cordova Plugin

Tags: java, cordova-plugins

**Context :** I'm creating a custom Cordova plugin that uses a scanner native functions such as scan, print, display scanned document *(the scanner have a screen on it just like a tablet)*.

The code by itself is working fine *(the scanner is running on an Android OS)*, things gets tricky when i want to "convert" the code to a Cordova Plugin *(i have already done that for another project and it worked perfectly)*.

---

**Problem :** In order to use the method that starts the scan i have to make sure that the said method in `ScanService.java` *(= it's an interface that has an `Abstract Class Stub extends android.os.Binder implements my.package.name.ScanService` )* is binded and can be used via an intent like this :

```
Context ctx = this.cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext();

public boolean BindServiceContext(Context ctx)
    {       
        Intent myintent = new Intent("name.of.package.ScanService");
        myintent.setPackage("name.of.package"); 

        ctx.startService(myintent);

        return ctx.bindService(myintent, ScanServConn, ctx.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }
```

The ScanServConn variable :

```
public ScanService mService;

public ServiceConnection ScanServConn = new ServiceConnection()
    {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service)
        {
            mService = ScanService.Stub.asInterface(service);

            try
            {
                mService.initService(mScanCK);
                mService.registerSystemCallBack(mSysCK);
                mService.mountScannerDevice();
            }
            catch (RemoteException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name)
        {
            try
            {
                if (mService != null)
                {
                    mService.unmountScannerDevice();
                    mService.unregisterSystemCallBack(mSysCK);
                    mService.unregisterCallBack(mScanCK);
                    mService.uninitService();
                }
            }
            catch (RemoteException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            mService = null;
            mSysCK = null;
            mScanCK = null;
        }
    };
```

At this point, the BindingServiceContext method returns `false`.

```
private void StartScan(String strScanProfilePath) //
    {
        try
        {
            int iRet = mService.getScannerDeviceStatus();

            if ( iRet == Defination.PAPER_STATUS_ON_TRAY)
            {
                int ret = mService.setScanProfile(strScanProfilePath);

                if (ret == Defination.ERROR_SUCCESS)
                {
                    // Start scanning.
                    mService.scanStart();

                }
            }

        }
        catch (RemoteException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The precise error i have when adding the plugin into a cordova project and testing it :

```
Attempt to invoke interface method 'int my.package.name.ScanService.getScannerDeviceStatus()' on a null object reference.
```

In my `plugin.xml` i have added this line, so in the `AndroidManifest.xml` of the project my service is declared :

```
<config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/manifest/application">
        <service android:name="my.package.name.ScanService" />
</config-file>
```